# Run another command before running the command the user wants to run

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, alias

Let's say I want to modify the original behavior of the `ls` tool this way:

```
$ ls
Hello World
file1 file2 ...
```

How can I do this?

When running `ls` I would like to run another command let's say `echo "Hello World!"`.

The quick solution I see is using alias:

```
alias orig_ls="ls"
alias ls='echo "Hello World!"'
```

However, this is not a real solution since when I will run `orig_ls` it will output `"Hello World!"`.

Comment: Put another ls in the users own path and use this to hook the original.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sometimes an alias isn't powerful enough to easily do what you want, so here's a way without using them.

In some file that is sourced when your shell starts (e.g. `.bashrc`), add the following function:

```
ls () {
    echo "Hello world!"
    command ls "$@"
}
```

Unlike an alias, a function can recurse. That's why `command ls` is used instead of `ls`; it tells your shell to use the actual `ls` instead of the function you've just defined.

Comment: Indeed. This solution scales better. +1

Comment: What is the `command` alternative for OS X?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I have no idea `command` didn't work :/ I have no idea and I don't have a Mac with which to test it, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

You must not forget to call `ls`:

```
alias ls='echo "Hello World!"; ls'
```

Comment: Ha! I supposed this will create an infinite cycle! But why doesn't it create an infinite loop?

Comment: You might instead try alias ls 'echo "Hello World!"; /usr/bin/ls'

Comment: @IonicăBizău any given "alias expansion rule" is only used once.

Comment: Would joining the two with an & also work? That would also ensure that the user's command is only run if the custom one works, right?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You can use `&` indeed but I don't get the argument you make from that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Never mind. I'll ask my own question if I absolutely need to know but until then I'd rather not piggyback on another.

Comment: @IonicăBizău The reason there is no infinite recursion is given in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases): *The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second time. This means that one may alias ls to "ls -F", for instance, and Bash does not try to recursively expand the replacement text*